# RegEx replace in Notepad++

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I have a huge XML file and I want to do a mass replace in it.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<xsl:if test="EVN_1_EventTypeCode">
    <EVN_1_EventTypeCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="EVN_1_EventTypeCode/text()" />
    </EVN_1_EventTypeCode>
</xsl:if>
<EVN_2_RecordedDateTime>
    <xsl:if test="EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent">
        <TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
            <xsl:value-of select="EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text()" />
        </TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
    </xsl:if>
</EVN_2_RecordedDateTime>
<xsl:for-each select="EVN_3_DateTimePlannedEvent">
    <EVN_3_DateTimePlannedEvent>
        <xsl:if test="TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent">
            <TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
                <xsl:value-of select="TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text()" />
            </TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
        </xsl:if>
    </EVN_3_DateTimePlannedEvent>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now I want to replace every test:

```
<xsl:if test='bla'>
```

has to become

```
<xsl:if test='bla/text()'>
```

So as you see I want to add "/text" to every test in de xml file.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `<xsl:if test='(.*)'>`
Replace with: `<xsl:if test='\1/text'>`